Getting subscribed topics from Firebase
Im trying to update the code that gets the subscribed topics of a user use react-native-firebase and Google apis
async function getInscricoes() {
    fetch(`https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/${await messaging().getToken()}?details=true`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `MY PRIVATE KEY`,
            'access_token_auth': true
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            if (response.rel?.topics) {
                const { topics } = response?.rel;

                setTopicos([...new Set(Object.keys(topics))]);
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e)
        })
}

The code above is what im currently doing. It currently returns [TypeError: Network request failed]. When tried on Insomnia, returns the Google login page.
It is needed to authenticate using react-native-firebase/iid now?
